# Hibernate/Suspend in Arch/Antergos doesn't seem to work on MacBook Pro 11,4

Tags: arch-linux, macintosh, hibernate, antergos

Whenever I close my laptop lid, or hit the power button, the machine appears to go to sleep. But when I return later, the machine is still running and taking power. Which has caused my machine to die from power loss when not plugged in. I am also unable to resume from the sleep/hibernation, as I just get a black screen.

I have followed the instructions here

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mac#Suspend_and_Hibernate

but the setting in `dconf-editor` were already set to `normal`. It says it works out of the box. I have tried the different available options in the power settings but nothing seems to work.Was hoping others might know how to solve this problem.

my file `/proc/acpi/wakeup` has the following:

```
$ cat /proc/acpi/wakeup
Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
PEG0      S3    *disabled  pci:0000:00:01.0
PEG1      S3    *disabled  pci:0000:00:01.1
PEG2      S3    *disabled
EC    S4    *disabled  platform:PNP0C09:00
GMUX      S3    *disabled  pnp:00:03
HDEF      S3    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1b.0
RP03      S3    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.2
ARPT      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:03:00.0
RP04      S3    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.3
XHC1      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:14.0
ADP1      S4    *disabled  platform:ACPI0003:00
LID0      S4    *enabled   platform:PNP0C0D:00
```

and my dconf settings

[image]